# Does ruby geocoder gem consume quota imposed by providers to get latitude/longitude and country code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, geocoding, rails-geocoder

While working with the geocoder gem I have found some condition based codes like:

```
def geocoder_lookup
  if country_code == "RU"
    :yandex
  elsif country_code == "CN"
    :baidu
  else
    :google
  end
end
```

All I want is to store latitude/longitude and country code. If I do that, does it consume my API quota? If it does, does it consume extra quota for reverse geocoding?

Answer (score 0):

for development phase you dont need to wory about this as if you are using google .they provide something 25000/day requests which is sufficient but when your application is live and when the number of users are increasing ...so the number of request will also increase,hence you will run out of the quota and will have to use a premium package which is also not very costly.LOOK [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#limitexceeded)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Geocoder consumes quota from whichever service you have configured it to use.

Comment: Does it mean if I store latitude, longitude and country code, it will send 3 requests?

Comment: It's my understanding that it dings you on the query side, not the storage side.